# unable to install javabridge with pip on macOS Monterey (m1)

Tags: python, java, jvm

when trying to install with "python3 -m pip install javabridge"
i get a very long error message that ends with this

```
   25 warnings and 2 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8h/hkmcg37d1_b6f6jq7qlhzzk00000gn/T/pip-install-uw2m_ckh/javabridge_c69e21afe5d44091bab36d7f0fddc92d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8h/hkmcg37d1_b6f6jq7qlhzzk00000gn/T/pip-install-uw2m_ckh/javabridge_c69e21afe5d44091bab36d7f0fddc92d/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8h/hkmcg37d1_b6f6jq7qlhzzk00000gn/T/pip-record-1kv_6_sp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/zeke/Library/Python/3.9/include/python3.9/javabridge Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried deleting later versions of java and re-downloading the java jdks and i made sure i have both the jre8 and jdk8 installed